# Invoking function in event handler returns desired results but referencing the method does not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

I'm having a real hard time grasping this keyword and how it works with regards to react. I know the correct answer to my problem, but I don't understand WHY it works and my other solutions do not. `this.showTime.bind(this)` is telling the showTime method to use the Contact object as this in the `showTime` method. (unless this is part of my misunderstanding).

Here's is my code with a few diff examples.

```
import React from 'react';
import Users from './Users.js';

class Contact extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
    this.showTime = this.showTime.bind(this); // correct solution
}

showTime() {
    console.log(this.state);
    console.log('tom');
};



render(){
    const { name, email, phone } = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                {console.log(this)}
                <h4> onClick ={this.showTime} className="click">click me</h4>
                // WORKS BUT THIS.STATE IS UNDEFINED
                <h4> onClick ={this.showTime()} className="click">click me</h4>
                // WORKS
                <h4> onClick ={contact.prototype.showTime} className="click">click me</h4>
                // WORKS BUT THIS.STATE IS UNDEFINED
                <h4> onClick ={this.showTime.bind(Contact)} className="click">click 
                    me</h4>
                // WORKS BUT THIS.STATE IS UNDEFINED
                <h4>email: {email}</h4>
                <h4>phone: {phone}</h4>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Contact;
```

Why does invoking the function in the handler give me the desired results compared to just `this.showTime`?

Logging `this` keyword inside of the render returns the Contact object so `Contact.prototype.showTime.bind(Contact)` or `this.showTime.bind(Contact)` should in theory work but they don't.

I know that `this` keyword has no scope and that it loses context when nested. It's strict when defined in class context so it doesn't return the window object. I just can't seem to understand what I'm missing here.

Comment: what is the difference between `this` and `Contact`?

Comment: `this` references the object that is executing the current function. Contact is the class or constructor object.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some prematurely closed h4 tags in your example but I assume those are just typos. Aside from that here are some notes that might help:

- `<h4 onClick={this.showTime}>` - 'this' should be calling and logging state correctly if you have showTime bound in the constructor or instead you can also use an ES6 arrow function to bind it: `showTime = () => {...}`
- `<h4> onClick={this.showTime()}>` - 'this' is referring to showTime correctly but it's calling it immediately and not onClick. You could use `<h4> onClick={() => this.showTime()}>` to allow it to be called onClick but writing it this way is unnecessary in this case since no arguments are being passed and you've already bound showTime in the constructor. A benefit of using an arrow function in-line like this is that it's another way to bind the function without having to bind it in the constructor
- `<h4> onClick={Contact.prototype.showTime}>` - I believe this (Contact with a capital C) should correctly refer to where showTime exists in the prototype chain but I think it's then not being referenced in relation to an instance of the Contact component.
- `<h4> onClick={this.showTime.bind(Contact)}` - if you replace Contact with 'this' it should work as expected (note that this is an accepted way of binding but it may cause some performance issues). I'm not sure why calling it as you have it causes showTime to run but shows undefined state. It may have something to do with what React does behind the scenes. When I log 'this' from showTime while calling it the way you have it the console shows the Contact class as bundled by Webpack.

Sorry I don't have more definitive answers on what's going behind the scenes with the 3rd and 4th examples, but unless you're really curious and want to know why they're working that way I wouldn't worry about it too much and just stick to the prescribed ways of binding in React. Here's a good article showing the various methods: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56/